# App fecha ao clicar em botão onClickListener

Tags: java, android, mobile

Olá, tudo bem? Eu criei um app de cadastro de pessoas no Android Studio e estou tendo alguns problemas... Toda vez que clico no botão de cadastro, ao invés de listar o cadastro realizado o app fecha...

Segue o código do meu MainActivity:

```
package com.example.cadastro;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText nome, idade, email;
private RadioButton masculino, feminino, intersexo, prefiroNaoDizer;
private TextView textNome, textIdade, textEmail, textSexo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nome = findViewById(R.id.editNome);
    idade = findViewById(R.id.editIdade);
    email = findViewById(R.id.editEmail);

    masculino = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonMasc);
    feminino = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFem);
    intersexo = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonInt);
    prefiroNaoDizer = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonNao);

    textNome = findViewById(R.id.textNome);
    textIdade = findViewById(R.id.textIdade);
    textEmail = findViewById(R.id.textEmail);
    textSexo = findViewById(R.id.textSexo);

    Button botaoCadastro = findViewById(R.id.btCadastrar);

    botaoCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String Nome = nome.getText().toString();
            String Idade = idade.getText().toString();
            String Email = email.getText().toString();

            if (Nome.isEmpty() || Idade.isEmpty() || Email.isEmpty()){
                Snackbar.make(view, "Não deixe de preencher todos os campos :)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                btSelecionado(view);
            }
        }
    });
}
private void btSelecionado(View view) {
    if(masculino.isChecked()) {
        textNome.setText((CharSequence) textNome);
        textIdade.setText((CharSequence) textIdade);
        textEmail.setText((CharSequence) textEmail);
        textSexo.setText("Sexo: Masculino");
    }else if(feminino.isChecked()) {
        textNome.setText((CharSequence) textNome);
        textIdade.setText((CharSequence) textIdade);
        textEmail.setText((CharSequence) textEmail);
        textSexo.setText("Sexo: Feminino");
    }else if(intersexo.isChecked()) {
        textNome.setText((CharSequence) textNome);
        textIdade.setText((CharSequence) textIdade);
        textEmail.setText((CharSequence) textEmail);
        textSexo.setText("Sexo: Intersexo");
    }else if(prefiroNaoDizer.isChecked()) {
        textNome.setText((CharSequence) textNome);
        textIdade.setText((CharSequence) textIdade);
        textEmail.setText((CharSequence) textEmail);
        textSexo.setText("Sexo: Prefiro não dizer");
    }else{
        Snackbar.make(view, "Lembre de marcar o seu sexo ;)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

O AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cadastro">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Cadastro">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

E também o layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/cadastro_de_pessoas"
    android:textColor="#01385C"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="34dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editNome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nome Completo"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLength="45"
    android:minHeight="48dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editIdade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Idade"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:minHeight="48dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email@email.com.br"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:minHeight="48dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Sexo:"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonMasc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Masculino"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonFem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Feminino"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonInt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Intersexo"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonNao"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prefiro não dizer"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCadastrar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="Cadastrar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textIdade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textSexo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


    
    </LinearLayout>
```

E o código de erro que aparece no Logcat quando clico no botão:

```
2022-01-14 13:11:52.155 19182-19182/com.example.cadastro 
   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2022-01-14 13:11:52.204 19182-19182/com.example.cadastro 
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.cadastro, PID: 19182
   java.lang.ClassCastException: 
   com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast 
   to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos

Answer (score 0):

Opa, João!
O erro aí está ocorrendo provavelmente por que está tentando converter em sequência de caracteres o MaterialTextView, tente alterar para o getText().
**Exemplo abaixo:**

```
if (masculino.isChecked()) {
            textNome.setText(textNome.getText());
            textIdade.setText(textIdade.getText());
            textEmail.setText(textEmail.getText());
            textSexo.setText("Sexo: Masculino");
        }
```